# python calling function calculate

Tags: python, function

What is wrong with this code? I'm trying to get 11 as a result.

```
def operation(a,b):
    return a + b

def calculate(a, b, operation):
    print("Parameter a=" + str(a) + ", b=" + str(b) + ", operation=" + str(operation))
    b = operation(a, b)
    return b

calculate(5,6, operation)
```

Comment: Try debugging into the code and watching how your expected results differ from actual. You might also share what results you _are_ getting.

Comment: What do you *think* is wrong with it? How do you know *anything* is wrong with it? Are you getting an error? Are you getting an unexpected result? Help us to help you!

Comment: And you are... What seems to be the issue? Apart from the `str(operation)` which probably isn't giving you what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with your code. However if you just want it to display the results, modify your code to the following:

```
def operation(a,b):
    return a + b

def calculate(a, b):
    print("Parameter a=" + str(a) + ", b=" + str(b))
    return operation(a, b)

print(calculate(5,6))
```

Comment: If you hint there are multiple issues.. why solely zooming into only one? Why not stating what else is not correct? Kinda pointless to mention so much is wrong...! Just display is not what OP asks.

Comment: The example code fixes all issues without directly pointing them out. There is no need to assign b to the function and return it when you can directly return the function.